# Is there any package for React native component like this?

Tags: react-native

[image]

Is there any npm package for React native for a component something like this on the photo?

Comment: The component is called a "Floating Action Button with Speed Dial."  See [this page](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/#types-of-transitions).

Comment: And if you Google "React Native Floating Action Button" you wind up [here](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/#types-of-transitions).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-floating-action